# Difference between return followed by curly braces and return followed by curly braces in next line

Tags: javascript

```
function a(){
 return{
    bb:"a"
 }
}

and 

function a(){
 return
 {
    bb:"a"
 }
}
```

Is there any difference between the two code, if yes please explain.

Comment: The only issue that can happen is when Automatic semicolon insertion happens then in second case `return` will return nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is huge. The first returns an object. The second - undefined due to [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion). `return` will become `return;`

```js
function a(){
 return{
    bb:"a"
 }
}


function a1(){
 return
 {
    bb:"a"
 }
}

console.log(a(), a1())
```

Comment: just a footnote: ASI stands for "Automatic Semicolon Insertion" -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the Javascript bods decided that a single `return` on a line will be subject to a sort of "auto-correct" mechanism called *Automatic Semicolon Insertion*.

So your second snippet becomes

```
function a1(){
 return;
 {
    bb:"a"
 }
}
```

which is no longer syntactically valid!

Reference: [What are the rules for JavaScript's automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

(I'm currently learning Javascript myself and have already fallen for this.)

Comment: Ok . I can die in shame now :D Have an upvote for the new thing today.

Comment: @SureshAtta: Could you have a robust conversation with the dudes who decided this was a good idea first? You can be the fall guy! Luckily for me, I use K&R style for C and C++, so this won't jab me too often.